# Lower bound of first moment of $L$-function on $\mathrm{GL}(3)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Let $\pi$ be an automorphic form on $\mathrm{GL}(3,\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$. 
Do we know any case that
\[\int_0^{T} \left|L(\frac{1}{2} + it, \pi)\right| dt \gg T\]
holds unconditionally?

I know the conjectured asymptotic formula is $T \log^* T$.

Comment: Yes, this kind of lower bound in $t$-aspect is trivial for any $L$-function.  The point is that you can approximate $L(\frac 12+it)$ by some long Dirichlet polynomial $\sum_{n\le T^{r}} a(n)n^{-1/2-it}$, say, with $a(1)=1$, and the $L$-function coming from $GL(r)$, say.  If you now integrate with smooth weights $L(1/2+it)$ (without absolute values), then note that only the term $n=1$ contributes.  The rest of the terms cancel out and are negligible for smooth weights (rapid decay of Fourier transforms).  So the bound $\gg T$ follows.

Answer (score 4):

see http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-11/S0002-9939-09-10012-6/S0002-9939-09-10012-6.pdf  ,where the low bound $T$ was obtained unconditionally for any $G_m(\mathbb{Q_A})$ and any power of positive real $k$.